# Hashed password - store as base 64 string in SQL server vs store as varBinary

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, security, passwords

I have a hashed password to store in my SQL Srever database

Not sure whether to convert it to a base 64 string before storage or whether to store it as `varbinary`.

If it was base 64 it would be easier to deal with in my C# but I am not sure if there are drawback to that approach.

Comment: I cannot think of a disadvantage. I'm using the base 64 approach too. I'm not sure if it consumes a bit more storage space. But even if it does... so what?

Comment: Since the trend is to de-optimize hashing functions, slowing it down with base64 should not be an issue :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no security drawbacks to using base 64, since it is simply a different representation for binary data, *as long as* you don't consider the Base 64 as adding a layer of security.  Since Base 64 is easily decoded by anyone (since it uses no key), it is *not* a security layer but rather just a different format.  I emphasize this because I've seen a lot of vulnerabilities resulting from the usage of Base 64 to obfuscate sensitive data.  The data was easily recovered by the attacker (me in this case.  Don't worry, this was in academia for a security class ;-) ).  All sensitive data should be encrypted with a secret key from the server.

I prefer to use Base 64 myself, since it can be processed easily as a string.  I always convert binary data to Base 64 after it's encrypted.

As explunit mentioned in comment, it will slow down your algorithm a bit.  However the slowing down of the algorithm by spending cycles converting to Base 64 is actually a plus for security since it makes a brute-force cryptographic attack less feasible for the attackers.

Comment: If the attacker has access to the complete table, wouldn't converting a column from base64 to byte[] or vice a versa be trivial (in both time and resources required)? The defender on the other hand saves some CPU cycles converting byte[] to string to byte[].